# Integer to string or wstring converter

Tags: c++

I can't use `std::to_string` and `std::to_wstring` function, so I have written a converter:

```
///@struct ParseInt
///Contains function that parses integer.
template<typename Char_T> struct ParseInt{
    static std::basic_string<Char_T> toString(int x);
};

///Converts integer to std::string
///@param x the integer to convert
///@return std::string from the integer
template<> inline std::string ParseInt<char>::toString(int x){
    int length = 2; //most ints coming here are 2 digits long.
    char* buf = 0;
    do{
        delete[] buf;
        buf = new char[++length + 1];
    }while(sprintf(buf, "%d", x) < 0);
    std::string str(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return str;
}


///Converts integer to std::wstring
///@param x the integer to convert
///@return std::wstring from the integer
template<> inline std::wstring ParseInt<wchar_t>::toString(int x){
    int length = 2; //most ints coming here are 2 digits long.
    wchar_t* buf = 0;
    do{
        delete[] buf;
        buf = new wchar_t[++length + 1];
    }while(swprintf(buf, length + 1, L"%d", x) < 0);
    std::wstring str(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return str;
}
```

I am not sure how efficient it is. Is there any solution that is more efficient?

Comment: For misunderstanding your original question I can give you at least +1 ;-)

Comment: There are a couple of problems: your buffer sizes are `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` (which is incorrect, as it doesn't correlate like this, to the max number of digits in an integer. Still, the solution will work. also, be careful about swallowing errors on failure: This version will keep working and simply provide invalid results to client code (I don't know your use case - maybe this is what you need, but it makes me wary :) ).

Comment: @utnapistim : it is incorrect but it will always be big enough, right? The max CHAR_BIT I will be working on is 32-bit

Comment: It should be fine.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure how efficient it is. Is there any solution that is more efficient?

Very inefficient.

First, you allocate buffers with new/delete. You should not do that. Second, you allocate in a loop. You shouldn't do that either.

Consider this code instead (function renamed to `to_string`, as what you do is not parsing - parsing would be the inverse operation - taking a string and extracting an integer from it):

```
auto print(char * buffer, int x)
{
    return sprintf(buffer, "%d", x);     
}

auto print(wchar_t * buffer, int x)
{
    return wsprintf(buffer, "%d", x);     
}

///Converts integer to std::string
///@param x the integer to convert
///@return std::string/std::wstring from the integer
template<typename C,
    typename T=std::char_traits<C>,
    typename A=std::allocator<C>>
std::basic_string<C,T,A> to_string(int x)
{
    C buffer[ 64 ] = { 0 }; // no new/delete required
                            // no loop required
                            // max int on 32bit architectures is
                            // 2,147,483,647; 64 bytes is "big enough"

    auto written = print(buffer, "%d", x);
    assert(written > 0); // should always be true
    return std::basic_string<C,T,A>{ buffer, buffer + written };
}
```

Advantages:

- there is no code repetition (easier to maintain)
- efficiency is linear in to_string (no loops)
- code is simpler and more straight-forward

Comment: Unix like systems don't have `wsprintf`

Comment: So, basically what you are saying that I should allocate the largest space possible and do it in one go..., is that right?

Comment: @Jahid, you are correct. Apparently, on Linux you would have to use [swprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/swprintf).

Comment: ... also, yes: you should do it in one go.

Comment: check out my new code, is it close enough? unfortunately the repetion can't be avoided, I have other versions (for `u16string` and `u32string`) that need template specializations..

Comment: just wondering, does the `wsprintf` function take `const char*` as format string?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that *if* you really have to do this, you might want to consider using `snprintf`. This lets you specify the size of buffer you're supplying *and* if the buffer you pass is too small, it tells you the size you do need.

```
// compute the length (including space for NUL terminator)
size_t length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", x) + 1;

// Allocate a string of that length:
std::string s(length);

// do the conversion:
snprintf(&s[0], length, "%d", x) + 1;
```

Unfortunately, there is no matching `snwprintf`, so a wide character version of this may be somewhat more challenging. One possibility is to compute the length by writing the data to a temporary file, the delete the file and use only the return value. This is fairly simple (much like the code above), but likely to be quite slow in most cases (though I've tried to benchmark it to see if it's faster or slower than repeatedly allocating bigger chunks of memory until `swprintf` succeeds).

Comment: `snprintf` is C++11, is it not?

Comment: C++11 and C99, so most compilers have had it for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have written it so that it can convert `int` to `std::string`, `std::wstring` (and to `std::u16string`, `std::u32string` when `>=C++11` is being used):

```
#include <string>       // std::string, std::wstring
#include <cstdio>       // std::sprintf
#include <cwchar>       // std::mbstate_t, std::swprintf
#include <climits>      // CHAR_BIT
#include <cassert>      // assert()
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    //These will be included if >=C++11 is used
    #include <codecvt>
    #include <locale>  // std::wstring_convert
#endif

template<bool B, typename T = void>
struct EnableIf{};
template<typename T>
struct EnableIf<true, T>{typedef T Type;};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct IsSame{ static const bool value = false; };
template<typename T>
struct IsSame<T,T>{ static const bool value = true; };



#if __cplusplus >= 201103L

///Convenience wrapper of std::codecvt (`>=C++11`)
template <class internT, class externT, class stateT>
struct Codecvt : std::codecvt<internT,externT,stateT>
{ ~Codecvt(){} };

///@struct ConvUTF
///`UTF-8 <> UTF-16` and `UTF-8 <> UTF32` converter (`>=C++11`).
template<typename Char_T>
struct ConvUTF { typedef std::wstring_convert<Codecvt<Char_T, char, std::mbstate_t>, Char_T> Converter; };
#endif

///@struct ConvInt
///Contains a function to convert integer to string (either `std::string`
///or `std::wstring` ( or `std::u16string` or `std::u32string` for >=C++11)
///@tparam Char_T Basic character type (`char`, `wchar`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`).
template<typename Char_T, typename T = Char_T> struct ConvInt{};

template<typename Char_T> struct ConvInt<Char_T, typename EnableIf<
IsSame<Char_T, char>::value|IsSame<Char_T, wchar_t>::value, Char_T>::Type>{
    //wrapper of sprintf or swprintf
    static int mysprint(Char_T*, size_t size, int x);

    ///Converts an integer to std::string/std::wstring
    ///@param x the integer to convert
    ///@return std::string/std::wstring from the integer
    static std::basic_string<Char_T> toString(int x){
        Char_T buf[sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT]; //sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT should always be sufficient
        int written = mysprint(buf, sizeof(buf), x);
        assert(written > 0);
        return std::basic_string<Char_T>(buf);
    }
};

template<> inline int ConvInt<char>::mysprint(char* buf, size_t size, int x){
    return sprintf(buf, "%d", x);
}
template<> inline int ConvInt<wchar_t>::mysprint(wchar_t* buf, size_t size, int x){
    return swprintf(buf, size, L"%d", x);
}


#if __cplusplus >= 201103L

template<typename Char_T> struct ConvInt<Char_T, typename EnableIf<
IsSame<Char_T, char16_t>::value|IsSame<Char_T, char32_t>::value, Char_T>::Type>{

    ///Converts integer to std::u16string/std::u32string.
    ///Uses codecvt for conversion.
    ///@param x int to convert
    ///@return std::u16string/std::u32string from the integer
    static std::basic_string<Char_T> toString(int x){
        std::string s = std::to_string(x);
        typename ConvUTF<Char_T>::Converter conv;
        return conv.from_bytes(s);
    }
};
#endif
```

Usage example:

```
int main(){

    std::cout<<"\nstring: "<<ConvInt<char>::toString(-48);
    std::wcout<<"\nwstring: "<<ConvInt<wchar_t>::toString(-2147483647);
    #if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    ConvUTF<char16_t>::Converter conv;
    ConvUTF<char32_t>::Converter conv2;

    std::cout<<"\nu16string: "<<conv.to_bytes(ConvInt<char16_t>::toString(-48));
    std::cout<<"\nu32string: "<<conv2.to_bytes(ConvInt<char32_t>::toString(-48));
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```